# C# - Is it possible to have a single .exe act as an application (when clicked) or a service (when run by windows)

Tags: c#, service, window

Is it possible to have an application that runs as a service if it is registered as such but if it is double clicked simply starts a regular interactive application?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes. You can use the `Environment.UserInteractive` variable. You will need to create a small wrapper around your service to expose the OnStart() and OnStop() methods since they are protected.

```
            var service = new MyService();
            if (Environment.UserInteractive)
            {
                service.Start(args);
                Console.WriteLine("Press any key to stop program");
                Console.Read();
                service.Stop();
            }
            else
            {
                ServiceBase.Run(service);
            }
```

**Wrapper Class (Make sure to extend `ServiceBase`)**

```
public partial class MyService : ServiceBase
{
    protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {
        //start code
    }

    protected override void OnStop()
    {
       //stopcode
    }

    public void Start(string[] args)
    {
        OnStart(args);
    }
}
```